# iframe alternative to HTML5 for pdf view

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, pdf-viewer

I want to display pdf file view in a division on a webpage for reading. I was using iframe for that. But as i searched about it. iframe is deprecated in html5.

Any other compatible(non flash and if possible not html5) way to show pdf content on webpage just like a pdf displayed with an iframe?

Comment: *iframe is deprecated in html5* — No, it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<iframe>` is not deprecated at all. At least, [the current HTML5 spec draft on `<iframe>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html) doesn't say anything about deprecation. In the future please read the specification itself before making ungrounded assumptions.

There's however an alternative to the `<iframe>` which allows graceful degradation: the `<object>` tag which in the below example gracefully degrades to a link when the specified content type is not supported by the browser nor any of its plugins (you know, displaying a PDF file inline requires the Acrobat Reader plugin).

```
<object data="/url/to/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="500" height="300">
    <a href="/url/to/file.pdf">Download file.pdf</a>
</object>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfectly acceptable use of an iframe.  It has not been deprecated in HTML5, it even has three new tags (sandbox, seamless, and srcdoc).  Or you can use `<object>` as the other answer suggests.